# Resolving base classes

Tags: c#, autofac

I got a class hierarchy with about 30 classes which is four levels deep.

For instance:

- Class1

  - Class1a

    - Class1ac
  - Class1b
- Class2

To that I got an interface called `IConsumerOf<T>`.

How can I get implementors of `IConsumerOf<Class1>` to also be invoked by all classes that inherit `Class1`? (without implementing `IConsumerOf<Class1a>` etc)

Edit: Adding a type constraint for the interface is not an option. And do note the `Autofac` tag.

Comment: Is this one for ContravariantRegistrationSource?

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt: I believe so. Add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
builder.RegisterSource(
    new ContravariantRegistrationSource());
```

Enables this behaviour :). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Declare the interface as `IConsumerOf<T> where T:Class1` instead

Comment: If you can't (or don't want to) change the interface you can use a implementation defined as `class Consumer<T> : IConsumer<T> where T : Class1`

Comment: The would make the interface fail for `Class2`, `Class3` etc.